Permission denied starting ffmpeg on MacCatalyst (MAUI)
I am using FFMPeg to code a cross platform app for Windows and Mac in Blazor Hybrid (Dotnet Maui).
One of the things I want to do is get information about a video file. To do that I am using ffmpeg and redirecting the stream in the code to capture the returned data in the code.
here's what it looks like
string ffmpegPath = Globals.GetFfmpegPath();
ffmpegProcess.StartInfo.FileName = ffmpegPath;
ffmpegProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = $"-i \"{videoPath}\"";
ffmpegProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
ffmpegProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
ffmpegProcess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
ffmpegProcess.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = videoPath;

But when I run this code, I am getting a permission denied error.
Any ideas what do I need to do to get this working.
The use case is simple. I want to run ffmpeg and get informatino about a file.
Thanks

What exception did it throw?

FYI Instead of ffmpegProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = $"-i \"{videoPath}\""; use ffmpegProcess.StartInfo.ArgumentList.Add( "-i" ); ffmpegProcess.StartInfo.ArgumentList.Add( videoPath ); as it will take care of correct quoting
